# Using filezilla work fine but when I'm using FtpWebRequest this error occur "unable to connect to the remote server"

Tags: c#, ftp, filezilla, ftpwebrequest

This error occur when :

```
   public void UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = "myFile";
            var ftpFilePath = "ftp://xxx.xxx.xxx/myfolder/";
            WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy();
            var ftpRequest = WebRequest.Create(requestUri) as FtpWebRequest;
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
            ftpRequest.Method = method;
            ftpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
            ftpRequest.UseBinary = false;
            ftpRequest.UsePassive = false;
            ftpRequest.EnableSsl = true;
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnValidateCertificate);
                var requestStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                int readSize = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                if (readSize == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readSize);
            }
            fileStream.Close();
            requestStream.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
```

When I use FTP on localhost and local network, it work well.
But when I try to connect to server with public IP address.
This error occur. When I use filezilla to connect to server with public IP address, it's OK. Please help me!!